# Do you really have to always satisfy Nyquist with all signals if your purpose is to reconstruct a signal?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, nyquist

If not, when can you not comply with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because this is a **sufficient condition** (for regularly sampled signals), and not a necessary one. This condition restricts the space of all possible continuous signals to a subspace of discrete sequences that contain the same information.

Suppose that you can constrain the signal space, eg limited band-width, positivity, parametric models, sparsity, etc. Then many theoretical works ensure perfect reconstruction (in theory) under Nyquist-like conditions. Literature abounds, under the names of [compressive or compressed sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing), sparse sampling, finite-rate of innovation, etc. Some are "exactly exact", some are exact within a high probability, under quantization bounds, etc.

The topic is very wide and active, I cannot provide more details unless the question is more precise. A couple of papers however:

- [A Systematic Review of Compressive Sensing: Concepts, Implementations and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1109/ACCESS.2018.2793851), 2018
- [Sparse Sampling of Signal Innovations](https://doi.org/10.1109/MSP.2007.914998), 2008
- [A Review of Sparse Recovery Algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1109/ACCESS.2018.2886471), 2018

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply!!